# Need Help on a custom HTML Helper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-views

I'm trying to create a custom HTML Helper to help simplify my masterpages menu, however it is not rendering on the HTML when I use it.. I'm thinking I will need to create a partial view, any ideas?

I did this..

```
    public static string CreateAdminMenuLink(this HtmlHelper helper, string caption, string link)
    {
       var lnk = TagBuilder("a");
       lnk.SetInnerText(caption);
       lnk.MergeAttribute("href", target);
       return lnk.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing);
    }
```

Now in my View, i have

```
<% Html.CreateAdminMenuLink("Home", "~/Page/Home"); %>
```

**Thanks: Dave Swersky**

**Fix was: I forgot the equals and removed the semi-colon**

```
<%= Html.CreateAdminMenuLink("Home", "~/Page/Home") %>
```

but when I look at the source, its empty.. tried adding <% using (Html.BeginForm()) %> and it adds a form.. but the link still doesnt come up.. debugged and the string works when i look at the watch, but does not render..

Any ideas?

Comment: Instead of editing to say thanks, mark the answer as 'accepted answer' by clicking on the checkmark in front of it :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your markup:

```
<%= Html.CreateAdminMenuLink("Home", "~/Page/Home") %>
```

The equals sign and no semicolon should do the trick.

Comment: Ha! It is always the small things I miss.. appreciate it, worked fine now! :)